# C# issues accessing another project's app.config

Tags: c#, app-config

I have two projects, one is an application (exe) and the other is a library (dll). I am loading the library dynamically from the application. I am trying to access the exe's app.config from within the DLL. Here is the code from the DLL:

```
config = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(ConfigurationUserLevel.None);
object abc = config.Sections["MySection"];
```

If I have a reference from the program project to the library project, then the above code works fine. But if I remove the reference I get a System.IO.FileNotFoundException.

The config's HasFile property is true, but it seems like it can't find the section or something. So I thought maybe it's using a different aap.config, and I tried to manually specify the app.config path into OpenExeConfiguration, but I still get the same error.

So how can I access the program's app.config from a DLL, without having a reference to that DLL from the program project?

Answer (score 2):

Solution:

[FileNotFoundException in Visual Studio Setup and Deployment Project when trying to load custom config](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1587911/filenotfoundexception-in-visual-studio-setup-and-deployment-project-when-trying-t)

I had to add my assembly to the resolve handler:

```
ResolveEventHandler tempResolveEventHandler =
(sender, args) => { return Assembly.LoadFrom(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location); };

AppDomain.CurrentDomain.AssemblyResolve += tempResolveEventHandler;
//access the app.config here
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.AssemblyResolve -= tempResolveEventHandler;
```